# A metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ for the Euclidean topology with all balls homeomorphic to an open annulus

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is there a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that any open ball is homeomorphic to an open annulus, i.e. to $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$?
It is quite easy to construct new metrics on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which generate the Euclidean topology: we just choose some continuous function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, and we can define a metric $m(x,y) = |f(x)-f(y)|+|x-y|$. If we take some weird function for $f$, for example $f(x,y) = w(x-y)$, with $w$ the Weiertrass function, then we can obtain a metric with complicated open balls (in particular, I think that no path-connected component is simply connected). However, it seems that this method will not give us something as nice as "all open balls are homeomorphic to an open annulus". Perhaps it is not possible to have such a metric, but I have no idea how to prove that. If we fix a point $x$, and we look at the balls $B(x,r)$ by moving $r$, we should see some part of the open annulus become finer and finer, until it disappears, and at that exact moment, a new hole must appear somewhere, and the process can start again.

Of course, it's just out of curiosity, it is not useful for anything.

Comment: It seems unlikely.  The catch will be the triangle inequality.  But I do not have a proof.

Comment: Balls are always convex and an annulus isn't so this is impossible.

Comment: @CyclotomicField balls need not be convex even if they generate the standard topology...

Comment: $S^1 \times [0,1]$ is compact. Having open compact balls means the metric space is zero-dimensional and so cannot generate the topology on $\Bbb R^n$. Maybe you want homeomorphic to $S^1 \times \Bbb R$ instead?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Oups yes of course.

Comment: Comment 1: A metric defined as you did with $m(x,y)$ gives you a pseudo-metric, unless the function is injective, am I right?

Comment: Comment 2: So, intuitively, the balls you're looking for should be homeomorphic to a punctured Euclidean (or equivalent) ball, so a ball missing a point. It looks like a metric wouldn't do it, since all metrics are equivalent in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but maybe a pseudo-metric could work?

Comment: @ManuelCañizares Response to comment 1: nope, because $m(x,y) \geq |x - y|$. Response to comment 2: "all metrics are equivalent in $\mathbb{R}^2$" I think you mixed up with the notion of norm.

Comment: @QuinnLesquimau, yep my bad, I did mix up metrics and norms. And indeed you're right about $m(x,y)$ being indeed a metric.